# function overloading c++?

Tags: c++

when compiling this simple code,i get this error:

[Error] no matching function for call to 'Studente::Registra()'

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Anagrafica{
public: 
    int codice;
    string cognome;
    string nome;
    void Mostra();
    void Registra();
private:
    bool registrato;
};
void Anagrafica::Registra()
{
    registrato=true;
}
void Anagrafica::Mostra()
{
    if(registrato){
        cout<<nome<<endl
            <<cognome<<endl
                <<codice;     
    }
    else
        cout<<"\nNon registrato \n";
}

class Studente : public Anagrafica{
    int anno;
    char sezione;
    bool promosso;
public: 
    void Registra(int, char);
    void Promuovi();
    void Controlla();
    void Mostra();

    Studente(){
        promosso = false;
        anno = 0;
    }
};

void Studente::Mostra()
{
    Anagrafica::Mostra();
    if (anno) cout<<anno<<" "<<sezione<<endl;
}

void Studente::Registra(int a, char s)
{
    anno = a;
    sezione = s;
}

void Studente::Promuovi()
{
    promosso = true;
}

void Studente::Controlla()
{
    if(promosso) cout<<"\nStudente promosso\n";
        else cout<<"\nStudente NON promosso\n";
}

int main(){
    Studente stud1;
    char risp,sez;
    int anno;
    cout<<"\nNome: ";
    cin>>stud1.nome;
    cout<<"\nCognome: ";
    cin>>stud1.cognome;
    cout<<"Codice: ";
    cin>>stud1.codice;
    cout<<"Anno Scolastico:  ";
    cin>>anno;
    cout<<"Sezione: ";
    cin>>sez;
    stud1.Registra(anno,sez);
    stud1.Registra();
    cout<<"Promosso? (s/n) ";
    cin>>risp;

    if (risp=='s') stud1.Promuovi();
    stud1.Mostra();
    stud1.Controlla();
    return 0; 

}
```

i dont understand the problem, shouldn't the function overloading should take care of the call for 'Registra()'?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [search for other questions related to your error first](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+%22no+matching+function+for+call+to%22+is%3Aquestion). Sadly there are upto 900 questions for this error message. Please consider editing your post to fix the code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because in child class `Studente` you declare `Registra()` with the same name in base class `Anagrafica`. This is not function overloading. The function in class `Studente` **hides** the function in class `Anagrafica`.

When you call `stud1.Registra();` it only searches for `void Registra(int, char);` in child class which does not have matching prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding `using Anagrafica::Registra;` in `Studente`.

That tells the compiler explicitly that you want the base class function to be considered when looking in `Studente`, rather than being hidden by your new function with the same name.